# How I can validate this pattern using regex

Tags: regex

I try to write a regex to validate a pattern, but I have some problems. 
This the pattern that I should get and validate using a regex

```
XXXX
XXXX-XXXX
XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX
```

Every X is an Int number [0-9]

I'm trying with this :

```
[0-9]{4}(-?[0-9]{4})?
```

but it gives me this pattern :

```
**4586-4584**-**5588-5558**-**5888-5545**
```

[image]

Any idea how to fix this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use `^[0-9{4}(?:-[0-9{4})*$`

Comment: Do you want to match 1, 2 or 5 appearances of `XXXX` (with hyphens, of course)?

Comment: @GalAbra I want to valide values like 5125  or 5125-3658 or 5885-9687-2545  the number of appearences of XXXX is 1 to 6

Comment: @ErrabiAyoub With every number of groups?

Comment: @GalAbra the max character of this pattern should not be more than 35 "-" included

Comment: @ErrabiAyoub Then it's possible to have even 7 appearances of `XXXX`. Take a look at my answer; Should be easy to adapt to whatever number of appearances you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern `[0-9]{4}(-?[0-9]{4})?` uses an optional hyphen `-?` and an optional group `(-?[0-9]{4})`.

The optional hyphen `-?` will allow for example 8 digits in a row (4 digits followed by 4 digits).

The optional group will allow only 0 or 1 occurances so XXXX-XXXX-XXXX will not match.

Not using anchors for the beginning and the end of the line, will match `3333-3333` in `333-3333-3333`.

You could update your regex to [`^[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{4})*$`](https://regex101.com/r/DglsNe/1), or with `\d`:
[`^\d{4}(?:-\d{4})*$`](https://regex101.com/r/SAipsX/1)

**Explanation**

- From the beginning of the string `^`
- 4 digits `\d{4}`
- A non capturing group to match a hyphen and 4 digits `(?:-\d{4})`
- Repeat that group zero or more times `*`
- The end of the string `$`

Answer (score 1):

```
[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{4})*
```

try this one, you need `-`, can't add `?` ahead it. add `*` instead of `?`, because may have more than one

```
(?<![0-9\-])[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{4})*(?![0-9\-])
```

this one will not match 1234-5667-78961234

Comment: This regex allows values likes 5858-8589-55858888

Answer (score 1):

```
^(\d{4})(-(\d{4})){0,5}$
```

If I understood correctly, you're looking for a pattern of `XXXX` (so every `X` is a digit) that appears 1 to 6 times, with hyphens in between.

Hence, the first 4 digits are **mandatory**, and then it's possible to have 1 to 5 appearances of `-XXXX`.

Note the `^` and the `$`, that make sure the regex doesn't match only a part of a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this pattern:

```
    (\b([0-9]){4}\b)|(\b([0-9]){4}\-([0-9]){4}\b)|(\b([0-9]){4}\-([0-9]){4}\-([0-9]){4}\b)|(\b([0-9]){4}\-([0-9]){4}\-([0-9]){4}\-([0-9]){4}\b)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Pj1xY2/3)

Comment: Thanks I try it it not working this regex allow values like 4588-5585-55546928

Comment: Upated. Maybe a shorted version but that one may work.

Answer (score -2):

This should do it. Only tried it using C# though.

```
[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}
```

Comment: This does not match 1234 or 1234-5678